# BGE Python: Mouse Sensor Error

Tags: python, game-engine, error, mouse

I tried to program something that makes the camera look at the mouse for one of my games, but it keeps giving this error on line.7:

```
Python.001(Camera), Python script error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Look.py", line 7, in <module>
KeyError: 'requested item "Mouse" does not exist'
Blender Game Engine Finished
```

The code on line.7 is this: `ms = c.sensors["Mouse"]`

c is the "currentcontroller" variable that I'm currently using.

I've watched tutorials and all of them give me this same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to BlenderStackExchange,

The <kbd>Mouse</kbd> string is a reference to a Mouse sensor with type <kbd>Movement</kbd> for receiving mouselook input.

Your setup should look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks that helped :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If my post seems to be the answer, please consider marking it as the thread solution.